# How to ignore any element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select only text from **td** by ignore 1122 from span.

```
$(document).on('click', 'table#tableid tbody tr td', function () {

    var types = $(this).
    console.log(types); 
});
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Text<span>1122</span></td></tr>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.firstChid.data` if there's nothing after the `span`. If there is, then iterate the `this.childNodes` collection and get the `.data` from each node that has `.nodeType === 3`.

Comment: What is expected result? just the word "text"?

Comment: Another way is create a clone...remove children of clone and get text from clone

Comment: @Charlitfl<
I want to get only text in table not 1122 in span

Comment: Its working for you?? https://jsfiddle.net/p9vL3xwm/1/

Comment: @CMedina not work it still select like 1122text
But I want is only text not that number

Comment: fiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/p9vL3xwm/2/ sorry, clone elemnt for no alter your content, remove span and get text

Comment: Note, no element at `html` at Question has `id` `tableid`